# Use case diagram includes

Tags: uml, use-case

I have a question regarding use case diagrams. As shown in the picture, the user is able to enter or update his name and his problem.

As you can see the user needs to enter both name and problem when entering his info for the first time (thus the includes). However,  if he wishes to update his info, wouldn't the diagram indicate that he has to modify both name and problem (since they are includes)?

This would be an issue if he misspelled his name but entered his problem correctly for example. Because it would mean he MUST update both name and problem.

Should I have two separate use cases where the "enter" one is made of includes and the "update" one of extends?

Thanks for the help!
[image]

Comment: Does the use case "User enters/updates info" have anything else apart from the two included cases? Why it is not possible to get rid of "User updates info" one?

Comment: Yes it has about the ten other includes. Not sure I understand your second question. Looking forward too hearing from you.

Comment: Johny, you can have optional includes as well. It's not because you include a usecase that it will be included in all scenarios. You might have scenarios that don't include a specific usecase. (and **no**, that doesn't mean you should use extend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pointless to extract included/extending use cases if you actually use them only once. Stay with `Enter/update info` as single use case and describe the above in the flow of the UC.

Stay away from include/extend in general since in almost all cases (I have seen) people just use it for functional decomposition. And that's not what UCs are all about. They are there to identify single added values the system under consideration delivers to its actors.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. In the case above, wouldn't "name" and "problem" be single added values? Surely the actor entering these values would have the ability to enter both of them separatly, so shouldn't they be considered as unique values to be used by the actor? It feels to me as if simply having "enter/update info" may not be specific enough.

Comment: It depends on the context. But then: would you consider "Enter first name" and "Enter last name" to be two different use cases?

Comment: Well I would probably put specifics elements that are at such a low level of abstraction in the UC description rather then on the diagram. Is that the right call?

Comment: You need to identify the added value. So (I don't know the domain) it could mean to have 2 UCs: `Enter personal information` and `Enter problem` as two individual UCs and leave away the general one. Just concentrate on added value, not on functions! This is the tough part for people that always think in program logic/functions. Read Bittner/Spence to get the right idea.